# Regular Expression Issue on Model Class

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model class with the following property for my country list.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a country")]
    [RegularExpression("^(?!----------------$)", ErrorMessage= "Please select a country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
```

At the moment when users click on any countries they will get the error message !?
I only need to display the error message when users click on `----------------` option only.

[image]

I have already tried couple of other expressions but they seem not work at all.
also tried this : `[RegularExpression("/^(?!----------------)$/"`
any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pattern that matches what is valid of course.  Also, do not use opening and closing forward slashes in your pattern.

An easy fix for the pattern you tried is to supplement the negative lookahead with `.+`:

```
^(?!----------------).+$
```

Here is [a regex fiddle for the tweaked version of your pattern](http://fiddle.re/bk7jt).

However, I would consider a pattern like the following judging by the countries in your list - and refine it as needed (e.g. for Unicode characters etcetera):

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)*( \([A-Z]+\))*$
```

Here is [a regex fiddle for this alternate (starting-point) pattern](http://fiddle.re/ftm5x).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still getting the error message for all other options as well.

Comment: Ahh great it works now! when I remove the `/` from the `/^(?!----------------).+$/` it just works fine. Thanks for that.

Comment: @AliShahrokhi: No problem.  Thanks for circling back to let me know that my first pass didn't work: I immediately noticed that the forward slashes were the remaining snag.